# How to download pipeline artifacts to user's browser by tasks like user select 'drop' to download ZIP file of build artifacts

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm working with Azure Pipelines, I want to provide an extra way to download a build artifact to the user's browser from Azure Pipelines-Release but I don't know how to do that. Does anyone know how?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To trigger the user's browser to download the artifact, you'd need to expose the URL to the artifact somewhere that the user can get to it. Unfortunately, there isn't anywhere in the Azure DevOps Release pipeline that can provide high-level summary information to expose this information.

For example, you can use the Azure DevOps REST API to get the [url to the downloadable artifact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/artifacts/get?view=azure-devops-rest-4.1&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops-rest-6.0). You could write the URL to the artifact in a build step, but the user would need to know to look through the log for this information. That's not making it easier for the user.

You could download the artifact using the `DownloadPipelineArtifact` task and then zip it up and then use the logging syntax to upload it into the log files.

[image]

The user could click the Download Logs button to download the artifact with the logs, but they would still need to know to click this button and to search through the logs for this info.

[image]

Wouldn't it just be easier to tell the user to click the link to the build that is already on the release?

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! I agree with what you shared. I am also using Azure DevOps REST API to get the Url and expose the URL to the artifact in the Description field. Before asking this question, I still think there is a better solution to achieve that but maybe, I have to be satisfied with what I am doing.
Thank you very much for your answer.